# file get contents again not working alternative

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I tried the curl as the filegetcontents now working in php can any one give me the solution so solve it using curl here is the code

```
$userData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);
print($userData[id]).'<br/>';
```

Comment: for Facebook Graph API the file_get_contents() should work and they never close the access. The problem is somewhere else. Did you try grpah exploer to see if this is working ?

Comment: no the problem is cpanel my hosting dont support that function. graph api works that perfectly but the problem is with my hosting so I have to use curl instead

Comment: in that case why not use PHP library for FB. What you are trying could be done by using the api end point `/me`

Comment: no bro thay is not working I tried it for normal case it works. I mean that I want to clean the expired token. for that I must use this. as I have to delete the expired token. so must use the above code.

Comment: Are you trying to make a GET or POST ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$cFb = curl_init(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'
);
curl_setopt($cFb, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$userData = json_decode(curl_exec($cFb), true);

curl_close($cFb);

print($userData['id']).'<br/>';
```

Although, as suggested by Abhik Chakraborty in the comments, it's probably worth looking into using the official [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk). The SDK uses curl so it should work in your hosting environment.

Comment: ok bro. I will surely try it. I am on mob now. I will surely reply and will comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields=name,id'),true);
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now you can get specific item like this:

```
echo $json_output['id'];
```